# security exception in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

while i am running my web application, i got the security exception like this what is that means how it comes can u tell details. thank u it is the eception

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

**Description of the  error is**

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add a `<trust />` element to your web.config like the exception is suggesting? See [trust Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx) from MSDN.